# Screen/Power management during media use

Tags: video, sound, hibernate, flash, multimedia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I stop the screensaver from turning on when I watching online videos?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144621/how-do-i-stop-the-screensaver-from-turning-on-when-i-watching-online-videos)

Is there a way to configure Ubuntu so it does not activate the screen-saver, sleep-mode, suspend and/or hibernate while music or videos are being used?

I normally have to move once in a while the mouse while watching a movie to prevent this.

BTW, I use VLC for everything.